# Aptana Studio 3 Slim support

Tags: aptana3, slim-lang

I am use Aptana Studio 3 for Ruby on Rails development. The project I am working on uses Slim (http://slim-lang.com/). I was hoping to find editor and formatting support for the slim file type. So far my Google search have some up empty.

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this --

Comment: If you are willing to switch to either Atom or Sublime, they have support for slim syntax highlighting (though you have to install the packages).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a poor solution, but Sublime (http://www.sublimetext.com/) have a template for Slim. Using the Package Control (https://sublime.wbond.net/) you can install it easily.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but you can get HAML syntax highlighting for slim files in Aptana Studio:

1. Open 'Preferences' (on Mac under 'Aptana Studio 3)
2. Goto 'General' > 'Editors' > 'File Associations' (or search for 'File Associations')
3. Click 'Add...' to add the '*.slim' file type
4. With the '*.slim' file type highlighted, select 'HAML Editor' from the list of 'Associated editors'

This at least gives you syntax highlighting for strings, symbols, some keywords (if, yield, etc.), and HTML id's and classes.

The bigger win for me is that the HAML Editor uses the better built in search that allows you to search the current file, open files, enclosing project, or the entire workspace. Before making that change a much more limited search was the default for slim files.